# NGX Datatable not sorting date by year

Tags: javascript, angular, date, ngx-datatable

I am working with NGX Datatables, and I have all my data sorting correctly, besides the dates. It seems that NGX's inbuilt sort is sorting from left to right, so it sorts the month/day but not by year. I am trying to sort with this format ('MM-DD-YYYY h:mm A'). If I change to this format ('YYYY-MM-DDh:mm A') it works just fine. I saw someone else said to use the pipe date in angular for dates, so I tried

```
{{value | date:'MM-DD-YYYY h:mm A'}}
```

but that also didn't work. It still doesn't sort the years. So it will sort the month and day, but the year will be mixed. Does anyone know a fix for this? And if not, is there  way I can add a custom sort to just one column?

I am currently using this configuration to allow the built in sort to sort all of my data.

```
 [sorts]="[{prop: 'status', dir: 'desc'}]">
```

I think I need to create my own sort for the date column though, if I can't get it to sort the year. Is there a way to keep the custom sort for all columns but one, and add my own sort to that column? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get the functionality I wanted, incase anyone else has this problem as well. I have the data from my backend bringing the date through as YYYY-mm-dd and then on the Angular side I am using their date pipe

```
{{value | date:'MM-DD-YYYY h:mm A'}}
```

to get the MM-DD-YYYY format that I want. It seems like as long as the value comes in with year first, it will sort it correctly.

Comment: It is extremely common to use YYYY-MM-DD for everything unseen and only change the format for presentation. That way you can do sorting and comparison lexicographically and don't need to convert strings to Date objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best way, but the only workaround to this problem was to write my own comparator.

```html
 <ngx-datatable-column prop="datumKnj" [comparator]="datumKnjComparator" name="Datum knj.">
  <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">
    {{value | date : 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

And the compare function is look like this:

```html
  datumKnjComparator(propA, propB, rowA, rowB) {
    console.log('Sorting Comparator', propA, propB, rowA, rowB);
    // do something with rowA and rowB objects.
    if (rowA.datumKnj < rowB.datumKnj) { return -1; }
    if (rowA.datumKnj > rowB.datumKnj) { return 1; }
  }
```